# Django: How to specify path to settings file

Tags: django, settings

I know this question has already been asked multiple times but I still can't seem to find a solution that works for me. My Django project folder looks like this:

```
my_project
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    my_first_app
    my_second_app
    core
```

Now the "core" folder looks like this:

```
__init__.py
some_other_stuff.py
settings
     __init__.py
     prod.py
     dev.py
     local.py -> dev.py
```

`local.py` is a symbolic link pointing to the right settings file, `dev.py` on my machine, `prod.py` in production.

Here's my problem: when I try to use manage.py, I get a weird error `ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` When I pass the path to the settings file local.py as an argument (`--settings=core.settings.local`) it runs fine. I figured the problem was that Django didn't know where to look for the settings file. How can I tell him (her?) where to look?

I already tried exporting the path to the env (`export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=core.settings.local`) and setting the `PYTHONPATH` to the parent directory, to no avail.

Comment: Try this: ```from .local import *``` in ```__init__.py```

Comment: @Mounir I just-I... I'm speechless. How? Why? Are you a wizard? Post that as an answer, explain why it works (if you know) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary use of `__init__.py` is to initialize Python packages. The easiest way to demonstrate this is to take a look at the structure of a standard Python module.

```
package/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
```

As you can see in the structure above the inclusion of the `__init__.py` file in a directory indicates to the Python interpreter that the directory should be treated like a Python package
`__init__.py` can be an empty file but it is often used to perform setup needed for the package(import things, load things into path, etc).

One common thing to do in your `__init__.py` is to import selected Classes, functions, etc into the package level so they can be convieniently imported from the package.

In our example above we can say that file.py has the Class File. So without anything in our `__init__.py` you would import with this syntax:
`from package.file import File`

However you can import File into your `__init__.py` to make it available at the package level:

```
# in your __init__.py
from file1 import File
# now import File from package
from package import File
```

[Source](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)

So for conclusion, when you call import in `__init__.py` in a package mypackage, it's like you use package as a simple python file, that's what my solution do:

`from .local import *` in `__init__.py`

I haven't use this before in the settings case but I use it when I wanna to subdivide my models in a Django app, `models.py` --> models package, `./manage syndb` doesn't discover my models declared, I found so this solution that's similar. You can find more details [here](http://www.acooke.org/cute/UsingaDire0.html)

Last thing, I'm sure there's others solution to your problem, but this can be the most simple.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You are in import hell somewhere. Had this problem too one time. The only way to find out where the root of your problem is, might be to disable all apps, try starting the server, enable the first app, start the server, enable the next etc.

BTW: your project layout should not be used from Django 1.4 onward. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py

I'd try to use the new layout and hope that it 'just works'.

Comment: We're gonna try changing the layout (it is the right layout after all). In the meantime the incantation from @Mounir seems to get the work done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the name of the file that the manage.py is looking for.

```
try:
    imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your    settings module.\n" % __file__)
sys.exit(1)
```

If you had the settings.py file in the same directory simple changing the 'settings' to 'local' would have worked.

But, since you have it in a different directory, I think you need to configure the settings. Refer to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True, TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True,
TEMPLATE_DIRS=('/home/web-apps/myapp', '/home/web-apps/base'))
```

Hope that helps.